# Cardinality of Sets Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question as such:

> Let $|A|$ denote the number of elements in A. For finite sets $A,B$,
>   prove that $|A\backslash B| = |A| - |A\cap B|$, where $\backslash$
>   stands for set difference.

Could someone show me how to prove it, please? I'm having difficulty working out a proof that feels rigorous enough - it seems too obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that for disjoint sets $X,Y$ we have that $|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|$. Take $X=A\setminus B$ and $Y=A\cap B$, observe that they are indeed disjoint, and simplify the equation.

Comment: Thanks! The concept of disjointness is useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$ and we have $A=A\cap(B\cup B^c)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c)$ and the sets in the last union are disjoint so
$$|A|=|A\cap B|+|A\cap B^c|$$
and we can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Direct Proof:

Suppose $|A| = x.$

Suppose $|A∩B|= y: y < x.$

Then, $x - y$ denotes the cardinality of all elements in $A$ and not $B$.

$A\backslash B$ is the set containing all elements in $A$ and not $B$.

Thus, $|A\backslash B|= x - y = |A|−|A∩B|$.