# Set Theory Laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have been working on the Inclusion Exclusion Principal and came across a problem where I am having difficulty identifying the transformation. 
 
Given Information: 
$\mid\mathrm{U}\mid = \mathrm{50}$ 
$\mid(\mathrm{A}\cap\mathrm{B})\mid = \mathrm{16}$ 
$\mid(\mathrm{A}\cap\mathrm{B})\cap\mathrm{C}\mid = \mathrm{7}$ 
$\mid(\mathrm{A}\cup\mathrm{B})\cup\mathrm{C}\mid = \mathrm{40}$ 
Find: 
 
$\mid(\mathrm{C}-\mathrm{A})-\mathrm{B}\mid$ 
[image: Solution] 
Using the Laws of Set Theory I can't see how to go from the first statement to the second and from the second to the third. Any help understanding this transformation would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the Rules of Inference, the transformation looks like it used the Rule of Disjunctive Amplification? I thought for set theory one could only use the Laws of Set Theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the first statement to the second**

For any sets $A, B, C$, $(C - A) - B = (A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)$. How one can prove this statement? We have to prove the following statements:

1. $(C - A) - B \subseteq (A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)$
2. $(A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B) \subseteq (C - A) - B$

I'll prove the first statement. The second is left to you.

Proof. Suppose $x \in (C - A) - B$. This means by definition that $x \in C - A$ and $x \notin B$. Since $x \in C - A$, it follows that $x \in C$ and $x \notin A$. But then since $x \in C$, $x \in A \cup B \cup C$. We also have that $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$, so $x \notin A \cup B$. Since $x \in A \cup B \cup C$ and $x \notin A \cup B$, we can conclude that $x \in (A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)$. Therefore, $(C - A) - B \subseteq (A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)$.

**From the second statement to the third**

$|(A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)| = |A \cup B \cup C| - |(A \cup B \cup C) \cap (A \cup B)|$ follows immediately from $|X - Y| = |X| - |X \cap Y|$, for any finite sets $X, Y$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514371/cardinality-of-sets-proof) question could give you a little more insight into how you can prove it.

Comment: So as long as $\mathrm{F}\subseteq\mathrm{G}$ you can replace $\mathrm{F}$ with $\mathrm{G}$?

Comment: What are $F$ and $G$? Elaborate on this.

Comment: $\mathrm{F}$ and $\mathrm{G}$ would be arbitrary sets. I was applying them to your proof of the first statement to the second. I was unaware that you could just replace a proper subset with the respective superset. Am I following the logic correctly?

Comment: I've only proved that $(C - A) - B \subseteq (A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)$ and left the proof of $(A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B) \subseteq (C - A) - B$ to you. To prove $(C - A) - B = (A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)$ you must prove both statements.

Comment: How can they be proper subsets of each other? Wouldn't one have to have fewer elements than the other to be considered a proper subset?

Comment: We say that $A$ is a subset of $B$ if every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$. The proper subset is a different thing. If $A$ is a subset of $B$, but $A$ is not equal to $B$, then $A$ is a proper subset of $B$. To prove $(A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B) \subseteq (C - A) - B$, let $x \in (A \cup B \cup C) - (A \cup B)$ be arbitrary and then prove $x \in (C - A) - B$.

Comment: Wow I was mixing up the symbol for proper subset and subset! Thank you so much Stavros!